# how to plot multiple time series in "month-year" x-axis ticks using ggplot

Tags: r

I want to plot multiple time series in a single plot window.

Individually also I am unable to do  it....then how to plot multiple time series....?

Here is the data

```
head(MP_rates)

   Month repo revrepo bankrate CRR  WPI
1 Apr-01 9.00    6.75        7 8.0 5.41
2 May-01 8.75    6.50        7 7.5 5.60
3 Jun-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5 5.30
4 Jul-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5 5.23
5 Aug-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5 5.41
6 Sep-01 8.50    6.50        7 7.5 4.52

sapply(MP_rates,class)
  Month        repo     revrepo    bankrate         CRR 
"character"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric"   "numeric" 
    WPI 
"numeric"
```

I tried doing this for a single time series:

```
rates$date <- as.character(rates$Month,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
rates$date <- as.Date(rates$date, "%B-%d")

head(rates)
   Month repo       date
1 Apr-01 9.00 2015-04-01
2 May-01 8.75 2015-05-01
3 Jun-01 8.50 2015-06-01
4 Jul-01 8.50 2015-07-01
5 Aug-01 8.50 2015-08-01
6 Sep-01 8.50 2015-09-01
```

This goes on till Sep 2015

```
ggplot(rates)+ geom_line(aes(x=date,y=repo))+ 
scale_x_date(labels =date_format("%b-%d"))
```

I'm not getting this single time series plot for the entire 15 years...it just plots one year data.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the format 
`scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%B"))`